# Selecting a Foreign Key MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I've 3 tables

```
Table: cm
    id      date                     title         body
     1      2013-01-05 18:36:58      SA v AUS      SA AUS Body
     2      2013-01-04 08:16:20      PA v AP       PA v AP Body

Table2: cat_post
post_id   cat_id           desc
  1            2           desccccc
  2            2           desccccc
  2            1           desccccc

Table3: cats
cat_id         name                cat_desc
  1            Category1           desccccc
  2            Category2           desccccc
```

I want to select all records from table cm whose id lies under specific cat_post.cat_id.

Suppose cat_id is 1, select all records from table cm whose post id has cat_id 1 in cat_post table.

I've used this query but this returns all rows twice (duplicate rows)

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from cm INNER JOIN cat_post ON cat_post.cat_id = 2;
```

Comment: What is `cm` table about? Categories? Posts? Something else?

Comment: cm about Posts, and cat_post has the reference of how many posts are in one category and how many categories are in one post

Answer (score 1):

If `cat_post(post_id, cat_id)` has a `UNIQUE` constraint, this will do:

```
SELECT cm.* 
FROM cm
  JOIN cat_post AS cp 
    ON cp.post_id = cm.id 
WHERE cp.cat_id = 1 ;
```

You could also use this:

```
SELECT cm.* 
FROM cm
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM cat_post AS cp 
        WHERE cp.cat_id = 1 
          AND cp.post_id = cm.id 
       ) ;
```

Comment: SELECT cm.* 
FROM cm
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM cat_post AS cp 
        WHERE cp.cat_id = 1 
          AND cp.post_id = cm.id 
       ) ;

This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: @MahmoudGamal You are joining (`cat_post` and `cm`) on `cat_id` while I think the OP means the join to be on `post_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cm.* 
FROM cm 
INNER JOIN cat_post cp ON cm.id = cp.post_id 
WHERE cp.cat_id = 1;
```